# Is it better to show testimonials one-by-one or all at once?

Tags: testimonials

I'm working on a landing page for a service my company provides, and the last section before the call-to-action contains a list of testimonials -- 3, in this case. Is it better to show this list expanded, showing all testimonials at once, or in a pager, only one testimonial being shown at a time? Is there any research/data on this?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there are any UX guidelines on this, but in my opinion -

It's best to show a few testimonials upfront; like 2-3. When you have more than 3 testimonials you can use a [thumbnail slider](https://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-image-and-video-gallery-with-thumbnails/) to display them in intervals. Make sure the slider is in autoplay state by default along with the controls.

In my experience on web this is the widely used pattern for testimonials.

**Examples (scroll down to bottom):**
http://principleformac.com/
https://www.uxpin.com/
https://marvelapp.com/pop/?popref=1
https://www.invisionapp.com/
https://balsamiq.com/

Answer (score 0):

**If you put all your testimonials out there in a chunk, you'd be pushing your call to action further down and I do not advise that.**

With the current trends, you have sections of product/service offerings on your website. Something like Intro, Highlights, Features, Pricing Options, Testimonials, Register(Call to action).

Each of these sections has certain height and a visitor has a certain mental model about what to expect in a certain section. That means, generally, a visitor expects the thumbnail slider of showing happy faces of customers and a couple of quirky lines informing how great the product/service is. It would be smart to stick with that paradigm.

A three/four testimonial rotating slider with pagination dots creates a good impression on user's mind. The user gets the feeling that there are many accolades for the product/service. So many that they need a pagination for that.

Usually, I have not come across someone who diligently reads each and every testimonial, because that falls somewhat on the accept terms and conditions type of content.

That does not mean you can not create something new altogether and show many testimonials in the designated height. A quick metaphor comes to mind is the world map. Assuming this applies to your context.

[image]

You can animate and open callouts from various areas of the world at certain time intervals. This will take you away from that simple slider and create something new at the same time limiting the height and the area for the testimonial section.

The above is just an example and you can create different visualizations to show more than the standard 3-4 testimonials. Make sure that you do not overwhelm the map or the user with lots of pins and too many testimonials.

**Bottom line is, showing all the testimonials will not fly well in most of the conditions.**